Identify this latin movie of teenagers killing people they don't like
I can't find this movie which I'm pretty sure is latin. Spanish I think.
It starts with a girl in a hotel, she is with a man which if I remember is here cheating on his wife. Then stuff happens and the girl kills the man. She calls her friends and they help hide the body etc.
And then after they create a "gang" in which they vote for one person to kill like each week and everyone has a role (killing, cleaning, ...).
The movie is about that, they choose people they want to get rid of and if they get enough votes it's the next to be killed by the gang.
I remember the fat guy supposed to get rid of the head but just hide it in his closet like a moron. There was also some love story and a guy saying to a girl in his bed that the body of a woman is like a temple (yes I remember that part, don't ask).
The title is something like : "Don't tell" or something like keeping a secret. But I'm not sure.
I saw this movie 4-5 years ago (not a very recent movie but around 2000 I think, maybe end of 90'). And it might takes place in Spain.
I'm searching this movie for a long time and that would be awesome if someone can find it :)

Welcome to the community. What year did you see it? Do you recall where the plot took place? I hope you enjoy this place as much as I have.

I guess event here no one knows :/ This movie is a mystery

I found it! The title is ''Don't say a word"! 
OMG finally! After so many years!!

We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations.

Yeah well, I asked that for me, shared the answered while I was not forced to. So I don't really care if you remove it
